# Cohomology(ies) of simplicial sheaves

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a topological space and denote by $Ab(X)$ the category of abelian sheaves on $X$. My question is on the category of simplicial abelian sheaves $[\Delta^{op},Ab(X)]$. A natural way to define a cohomology for these sheaves is to take
$$[\Delta^{op},Ab(X)]\overset{[\Delta^{op},R\Gamma(X,-)]}{\longrightarrow}[\Delta^{op},D(Ab)].$$
Is this the "right" definition for the cohomology of simplicial sheaves? For instance, does this functor respect weak equivalences?

I think another natural definition would be to say that the category $[\Delta^{op},Ab(X)]$ is abelian and to consider the the right derived functor of $s\Gamma(X,-):[\Delta^{op},Ab(X)]\to [\Delta^{op},Ab]$ which would yield a right derived functor
$$Rs\Gamma(X,-):[\Delta^{op},Ab(X)]\to D\left([\Delta^{op},Ab]\right).$$
How do these two functors compare? Could we have $[\Delta^{op},D(Ab)]\cong D\left([\Delta^{op},Ab]\right)$?

Comment: You haven’t defined what the weak equivalences are. Your first suggestion doesn’t interact with the simplicial structure at all, so it can’t be the right answer. Your second suggestion is better but the codomain of your cohomology functor doesn’t make use of the simplicial structure. Actually I’m not sure why you bring up simplicial objects at all if you know about derived categories in the sense of homological algebra. By the Dold–Kan correspondence you can embed simplicial abelian sheaves in chain complexes of sheaves and just do everything in that language.